# Use Website/Default checkbox for Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form field

Tags: adminhtml, scope, adminform

I have a form in the admin section that is dealing with a custom entity. This entity has a main table and then a table to store options on a store level. I am wondering if it is possible to use the same check-boxes on my form as are in the config or product edit page when the scope is changed.

My form extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form` and I add the fields as follows.

```
$fieldSet->addField(
        'field_code',
        'text',
        array(
            'label'    => Mage::helper('myhelper')->__('Field Label'),
            'class'    => '',
            'required' => false,
            'name'     => 'field_code',
        )
    );
```

I have already added the scope switcher via layout.xml and save the entity values for the scope in a separate table, which all works well.

But it would be great if the user did not have to enter these values if they wanted to use the default scope entry.

**NOTE:** I have seen some people use `after_element_html` before to add the elements but I thought there may be a core function that would do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this a solution to your problem, but it can be a hint in the right direction.
You can specify a custom element rendered in any one of your form tabs like this (the example is from the catalog module):

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    Varien_Data_Form::setElementRenderer(
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form_renderer_element')
    );
    Varien_Data_Form::setFieldsetRenderer(
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form_renderer_fieldset')
    );
    Varien_Data_Form::setFieldsetElementRenderer(
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/catalog_form_renderer_fieldset_element')
    );
}
```

The last method sets the element renderer block. You can try to use that but I think you will get some errors because that is destined for EAV entities.
You can create a block that extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element` and add a custom template to it similar to `catalog/form/renderer/fieldset/element.phtml` where you can add your checkboxes or anything else.